# How to parse incomplete/partial JSON in Go?

Tags: json, go, openai-api

Is there a way to parse partial/incomplete JSON strings into map/interface values? For example: `{"name": "foo` becomes `map[string]any{"name": "foo"}`

The need for this arises when using OpenAI's chat completion API with the stream option ([link](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/streaming)) and if you want to utilize JSON responses that uses functions (or tools) you get back [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Event_stream_format) messages like below:

```
{"f
iel
d:":
"val
ue"}
```

Which means these messages should be concatenated on the consumer side and the complete string is going to be a valid JSON string only when stream finishes, but this makes it impossible to update the UI as the response comes in.
There is a library for this in [JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/partial-json) and also in [Python](https://github.com/promplate/partial-json-parser) but could not yet find one for Go. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: You can use json.Decoder to parse incrementally

Comment: There's nothing in the stdlib to my knowledge to handle incomplete/gradual json parsing for you. You can either implement your own parser or (preferably) use `json.Decoder.Token()` to walk through and get tokens until you know your input is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The exact parsing you want isn't possible, because who says `{"name": "foo` is `{"name": "foo" ...` and not `{"name": "foobar" ...`?

As mentioned by coxley in comments, you can use `json.Decoder.Token()` to iterate over the JSON stream. The [jsoniter](https://github.com/simon-engledew/jsoniter/) package provides a wrapper around it (and the underlying code shows how you could do this yourself as well - it isn't that hard). You could also look into something like [bytedance/sonic](https://github.com/bytedance/sonic?tab=readme-ov-file#streaming-io) which provides a whole bunch of JSON encoding/decoding tools, though that may well be overkill.

The most basic variant what will parse each top level node one at a time would look something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // Get some io.Reader, this could be a streaming buffer
    r := getDataReader()
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r)

    // Read opening { - needed to "enter" the root level
    _, _ = dec.Token()

    // Loop over the root level
    for dec.More() {
        key, err := dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %s", err)
        }

        // Read the content of the current key
        // Important: if the content of the current key isn't read like this, and there isn't any recursion,
        // dec.More() will move into the data structure, but it stops as soon as it reaches the end of the first node that
        // is a simple value
        var val any
        err = dec.Decode(&val)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %s", err)
        }

        log.Printf("%s => %#v", key, val)
    }
}

func getDataReader() io.Reader {
    data := `{
        "first": {
            "name": "The First Thing",
            "count": 1
        },
        "second": {
            "name": "The 2d Thing",
            "count": 2
        }
}`

    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(data)

    return buf
}
```

This will do what you've described in the question. If your needs are more complicated (eg you need to get chunks at a deeper level) you'll need to add some recursion - jsoniter shows a nice and simple way to do that (or just use that library).

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a struct to contain a `json.RawMessage`, for example:

```
var jsonStruct struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1"`
    Field2 int    `json:"field2"`
    json.RawMessage
}
```

and only parse the fields that are already complete (or received):

```
func get(to interface{}, m map[string]json.RawMessage, s string) {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(m[s], &to); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    delete(m, s)
}

get(&jsonStruct.Field1, m, "field1")
```

and then parse the remaining json back to the RawMessage:

```
jsonStruct.RawMessage, err = json.Marshal(json)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. How would you call this function if you have an incoming partial JSON like this: `{"name": "foo` and let's say your struct is as follows `type Response struct { Name string 'json:"name"'; Age  int 'json:"age"' }`